# Facebook FQL. Table 'columns' contain wrong fields

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Why the next Facebook FQL:

```
select column_name from columns where table_name = 'user' order by column_name
```

return are different list of columns then in api page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

for example it return field 'can_viewer_send_poke_message' but facebook tell that

```
(#602) can_viewer_send_poke_message is not a member of the user table
```

So, I just trying to automate process to keep some hql queries with full list of Columns of each hql table.

**May be is there some other way to get for each table column list as string separated with ","?**

Comment: @Igy: Care to give us an explainer on this one?

Answer (score 0):

This is a private field for Facebook Developers of the Official Poke Application for iPhone. It checks whether the users listed (friends) can use the poke application.